# Generate create table statements in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, metadata, etl

I am trying to move data from postgres to sqlserver. I want to recreate the table from postgres in sqlserver by using the metadata.

information_schema has the column data types but I would need to parse the info to generate a usable create table statement.

Are there any modules out there that will do this for me?

I'm new to the python scene.
Thanks

jlj

Comment: Use `pg_dump --schema-only ...` and work from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use below query to get `create statement`, please pass the table name in `where` clause

```
select 'CREATE TABLE ' || a.attrelid::regclass::text || '(' ||
string_agg(a.attname || ' ' || pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid,
a.atttypmod)||
    CASE WHEN
        (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
         FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
         WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef) IS NOT 
NULL THEN
        ' DEFAULT '|| (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
                      FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
                      WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef)
    ELSE
        '' END
||
    CASE WHEN a.attnotnull = true THEN
        ' NOT NULL'
    ELSE
        '' END,E'\n,') || ');'
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a join pg_class on a.attrelid=pg_class.oid
WHERE a.attrelid::regclass::varchar =
'table_name'
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped  and pg_class.relkind='r'
group by a.attrelid;
```

Comment: I was hoping for some module that i could call to spit it out for me.Thank you for the query.